# invalid flatten layer when training keras reinforcement learning model

Tags: keras, reinforcement-learning, layer, valueerror, flatten

Whenever I try to fit my reinforcement model to the Atari Pong-v0 Gymnasium Enviorment,a value error for the flatten layer is raised saying:

'ValueError: Error when checking input: expected flatten_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 1, 2)'

this is the code

```
import gymnasium as gym
import random as rd
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers.legacy import Adam
from rl.agents import DQNAgent
from rl.memory import SequentialMemory
from rl.policy import BoltzmannQPolicy
import numpy as np

env = gym.make( 'Pong-v0',render_mode='human')
observation_space_shape = env.observation_space.shape
actions = env.action_space.n
#shape of observation space is (210,160,3)


model = Sequential()
model.add(Flatten(input_shape = observation_space_shape)) # This is where the error is coming from
model.add(Dense(units = 30,activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(units = 30,activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(units = actions,activation = 'linear'))


agent = DQNAgent(
    model=model,
    policy=BoltzmannQPolicy(),
    memory=SequentialMemory(limit=50000,window_length=1),
    nb_actions=actions,
    nb_steps_warmup=10,
    target_model_update=0.01
)

agent.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr = 0.001),metrics=['mae'])
agent.fit(env,nb_steps=10000,visualize=False,verbose=1)
env.reset()

results = agent.test(env,nb_episodes=10,visualize=True)
print(np.mean(results.history['episode_reward']))
env.close()
```

I tried changing the input shape of the flatten layer to (1,1,2) but that led me to this error:

'ValueError: Error when checking input: expected flatten_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 1, 2)'